# Yu-Gi-Oh!: If monarch Caius or Raiza is flipped face up its effect activate?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Let's say I have [Caius](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Caius_the_Shadow_Monarch) or [Raiza](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Raiza_the_Storm_Monarch) in hand. Then I tribute summoned Caius/Raiza but set it face down.

Q1- If next turn I flip it face up in Attack position, does it's effect activate?

Q2- If opponent attacks my set face-down Caius/Raiza, does it's effect activate?

Q3- What if I tribute summoned Caius/Raiza (its effect activated normally), then used [Book of Moon](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Book_of_Moon) to flip it face down, then flipped it face up in Attack position again, does its effect activate again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For their effects to activate they must be tribute summoned. In this case you (tribute)set them. Therefore, you won't be able to use their effects.

Comment: More specifically, OP is Tribute setting them, and *then* OP is flipping them face up, so yes no tribute summon per se.